# Get the corresponding python variable name of a Z3 model name

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

Is there a way to get the corresponding python variable name of a z3 model name?

Suppose I have the following code:

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

a = [Real('a_%s' % k) for k in range(10)]

for i in range(10):
    s.add(a[i] > 10)

s.check()

m = s.model()
for d in m:
    print(d, m[d])
```

Here the `d` in `m` are `a_0, a_1, a_2,..., a_9`, and all of their values are `11`. I'm trying to set up some constraints which make the variables don't equal to the previous checking result, like the following:

```
s.add(a[0] != m['a_0']
...
s.add(a[9] != m['a_9']
```

Therefore my question is that does Z3 has a method to get the corresponding python variable name of a z3 model name? If so, then I don't need to enumerate all the variables names. Because this will be a huge work if we have many variables. What I want to achieve can be the following:

```
m = s.model()
for d in m:
    s.add(corresponding_python_variabl_name(d) != m[d])
```

Does Z3 have that `corresponding_python_variable_name()` function? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to generate all possible models?

If that's the case, use the following template:

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

a = [Real('a_%s' % k) for k in range(10)]

for i in range(10):
    s.add(a[i] > 10)

while s.check() == sat:
   m = s.model()

   if not m:
       break

   print m

   s.add(Not(And([v() == m[v] for v in m])))
```

Note that this will loop as many different models as there are; so if you have many models (potentially infinite with `Real`s as in your problem), then this'll go on forever. (Or till you run out of memory/CPU etc.)