# How to restrict the index sort for an array in Z3?

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm trying to represent an array of 9 characters as an array in Z3 to enumerate all combinations of those characters that will satisfy certain constraints (which have been generated by KLEE).

The expressions that are generated are as below:

```
(set-logic QF_AUFBV)
(declare-fun ascii_buf () (Array (_ BitVec 32) (_ BitVec 8) ) )

(assert
    (let (
        (?B1 ((_ sign_extend 24)  (select  ascii_buf (_ bv8 32) ) ) )
        (?B2 ((_ sign_extend 24)  (select  ascii_buf (_ bv6 32) ) ) )
        (?B3 ((_ sign_extend 24)  (select  ascii_buf (_ bv7 32) ) ) )
        (?B4 ((_ sign_extend 24)  (select  ascii_buf (_ bv1 32) ) ) )
        (?B5 ((_ sign_extend 24)  (select  ascii_buf (_ bv2 32) ) ) )
        (?B6 ((_ sign_extend 24)  (select  ascii_buf (_ bv0 32) ) ) )
        (?B7 ((_ sign_extend 24)  (select  ascii_buf (_ bv5 32) ) ) )
        (?B8 ((_ sign_extend 24)  (select  ascii_buf (_ bv3 32) ) ) )
        (?B9 ((_ sign_extend 24)  (select  ascii_buf (_ bv4 32) ) ) ))

        (let (
            (?B11 (bvadd  (_ bv4294967248 32) ?B5 ) )
            (?B10 (bvadd  (_ bv4294967248 32) ?B4 ) ) )

            (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and (and

                (=  false (bvslt  ?B6 (_ bv48 32) ) )   # ASCII number constraints ("0" = 48, "9" = 57)
                (=  false (bvslt  (_ bv57 32) ?B6 ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  ?B4 (_ bv48 32) ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  (_ bv57 32) ?B4 ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  ?B5 (_ bv48 32) ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  (_ bv57 32) ?B5 ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  ?B8 (_ bv48 32) ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  (_ bv57 32) ?B8 ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  ?B9 (_ bv48 32) ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  (_ bv57 32) ?B9 ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  ?B7 (_ bv48 32) ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  (_ bv57 32) ?B7 ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  ?B2 (_ bv48 32) ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  (_ bv57 32) ?B2 ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  ?B3 (_ bv48 32) ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  (_ bv57 32) ?B3 ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  ?B1 (_ bv48 32) ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  (_ bv57 32) ?B1 ) ) )

                (bvslt  ?B10 (_ bv9 32) ) )             # other constraints (autogenerated)
                (=  false (bvslt  ?B11 ?B10 ) ) )
                (bvslt  (bvadd  (_ bv4294967248 32) ?B8 ) (_ bv9 32) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  (bvadd  (_ bv4294967200 32) (bvadd  ?B4 ?B8 ) ) (bvadd  (_ bv4294967248 32) ?B6 ) ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  (bvadd  (_ bv4294967248 32) ?B9 ) (_ bv9 32) ) ) )
                (bvslt  (bvadd  (_ bv4294967248 32) ?B7 ) (_ bv9 32) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  (bvadd  (_ bv4294967200 32) (bvadd  ?B4 ?B7 ) ) ?B11 ) ) )
                (=  false (bvslt  ?B11 (_ bv9 32) ) )

            ) # outer and

        ) # end inner let

    ) # end outer let

) # end assert
```

When I try to enumerate different solutions using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54115880/get-the-corresponding-python-variable-name-of-a-z3-model-name), I start to get unexpected models like this (the first 2 are as expected with constrained indexes < 9):

```
[ascii_buf = Lambda(k!0,
                    If(k!0 == 3,
                       56,
                       If(k!0 == 0,
                          51,
                          If(k!0 == 4,
                             57,
                             If(k!0 == 1,
                                56,
                                If(k!0 == 5,
                                   56,
                                   If(k!0 == 2, 57, 50)))))))]
[ascii_buf = Lambda(k!0,
                    If(k!0 == 3,
                       56,
                       If(k!0 == 4,
                          57,
                          If(k!0 == 1,
                             56,
                             If(k!0 == 5,
                                56,
                                If(k!0 == 2, 57, 50))))))]
[ascii_buf = Lambda(k!0,
                    If(k!0 == 3,
                       56,
                       If(k!0 == 1073741824,
                          48,
                          If(k!0 == 4,
                             57,
                             If(k!0 == 1,
                                56,
                                If(k!0 == 5,
                                   56,
                                   If(k!0 == 2, 57, 50)))))))]
[ascii_buf = Lambda(k!0,
                    If(k!0 == 3,
                       56,
                       If(k!0 == 1073741824,
                          48,
                          If(k!0 == 4,
                             57,
                             If(k!0 == 1,
                                56,
                                If(k!0 == 5,
                                   56,
                                   If(k!0 == 32768,
                                      51,
                                      If(k!0 == 2, 57, 50))))))))]
```

I'm not too familiar with Z3 but my guess would be if I could restrict the array's index sort (instead of it being from a 32-bit bitvector), this might fix the issue. But any/all suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Z3 arrays are unbounded (in size); if your array is of fixed size nine, then you'll be probably better of using nine constants `a0`, ..., `a8` to represent the nine array locations.

Comment: A common trick is to use constant arrays, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863754/z3-set-default-value-of-array-to-zero/54870302#54870302 But since you're using some other tool to generate these, I'm not sure if you can tell it to start from a constant array. That'd be the way to go if you can convince Klee to do it.